# Can't add apache tomcat server in netbeans

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, netbeans

Hi I am new to netbeans and want to install Apache tomcat. I am using osx 10.8.4

I download the zip file from `http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi`. I then unzip it and rename it to `tomcat`. After that copy that folder in `System/Library` folder and then in netbeans Tools->servers->Add server, here I gave the path of the `tomact` folder. But it won't install.

[image]

Comment: Netbean also comes packaged with inbuilt tomcat, which automatically get installed with IDE. why not use that.

Comment: I already downloaded the netbeans with out tomcat.

Comment: I just googled it and got below links: Try this - http://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/02/installing-tomcat-7-and-configuring-as-server-in-netbeans/ or this link - http://razius.com/2012/01/installing-and-adding-an-external-tomcat-server-in-netbeans/ Please post, if facing any difficulty.

Comment: Hi @gyan I just figure it out see my answer thanks!

Comment: This question should probably be closed because it's no longer relevant. Netbeans 8 works fine with Tomcat 8 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figure it out. According to `http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Netbeans-7-3-and-Tomcat-8-td5728321.html` netbean does not have support for tomcat 8. So I downloaded version 7 and now it works!!